# Power Bi visual in landing page (wx radar)

Tags: powerbi, embed, microsoft-edge, powerbi-desktop, openweathermap

I embedded the weather radar in a visual on the landing page. Used to work now the map won't load in Power Bi. Here is the link I used in the  Embed code section. When using CHROME browser it works, but not in EDGE. Any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Does not work:

```
<iframe src="https://radar.weather.gov" width="1600" height="500"></iframe>
```

Another map, does work, but don't like it:

```
<iframe style="display: block;" src="https://builder.zoomradar.net/zoomradar_weather_map/weather_page.php?key=0I7xUKuyEviV8oC" width="1000" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" loading=""></iframe>
```

Want the wx radar from the GOV page to work in PBIX landing page using EDGE browser.